# How do I make a list of type class, which has properties?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I want to create a list of type class which has properties which I can add to.

Also to be able to access these properties?

Here's what I have so far.

```
public class Class1 
{
    enum Player
    {
        Me,
        Opponent
    }

    public class MovesMade
    {
        Player Peep = new Player { };
        //Other properties here
    }

    List<MovesMade> AllMoves = new List<MovesMade> {};

    public void MyFunc() 
    {
        AlllMoves.Add ??

        if (AllMoves.Peep == Player.Me) {

        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: You're probably going to have to clear this up.  It doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a property of a class accessible outside of itself, mark it public.
Here is your example modified a bit to get you started.

```
public class Class1 
{
    public enum Player
    {
        Me,
        Opponent
    }    

    List<MovesMade> AllMoves = new List<MovesMade> {};

    public void MyFunc() 
    {
        MovesMade movesMade = new MovesMade();
        movesMade.Peep = Player.Me;
        AlllMoves.Add(movesMade);

        if (movesMade.Peep == Player.Me) {

        } 
    }
}

public class MovesMade
{
    public MovesMade(){

    }
    public Player Peep { get; set; }
    //Other properties here
}
```

Comment: This is my problem I get 'Error 1 Inconsistent accessibility: property type 'Class1.Player' is less accessible than property 'Class1.MovesMade.Peep'

Comment: You most certainly *can* have a class within another class.

Comment: Cool. Now I'm getting Error 1 The name 'AlllMoves' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Yes you're right, I apologize for misrepresenting the nested class.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your property is not well declared. Instead of

   ```
   public class MovesMade
   {
       Player Peep = new Player { };
   }
   ```

   Do:

   ```
   public class MovesMade
   {
       public Player Peep { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. To add a new `MovesMade` to the list, call your constructor:

   ```
   AllMoves.Add(new MovesMade());
   ```
3. If you want to set `Peep` directly when adding, either create a constructor that takes a `Player`:

   ```
   AllMoves.Add(new MovesMade(Player.Opponent));
   ```

   or use an object initializer:

   ```
   AllMoves.Add(new MovesMade() { Peep = Player.Opponent });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 MovesMade m = new MovesMade();
 m.Peep = new Player();
 m.Peep.Name = "foo";

 AlllMoves.Add(m);

 foreach(var moves in AlllMoves)
 {
    if (moves.Peep.Name = "Jules")
    {
    }
 }
```